# Retrieving image from PHPmyadmin to js

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, get

Ok I'm using mySQL to insert image. I am trying to use js file to get the image to display for my application. That of course didn't work.

[image]

**This is my html page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Approval</title>
        <script src="scripts/phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/administratormc.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/header.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome" rel="stylesheet">  
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <center>
                <div id="ph"><div id="bi">
                    <img src="images/back icon.png" alt="Logo" onclick="location.href = 'homepage2.html'" height="30" width="30" />
                    </div>
                    <img id="logoimg1" src="images/Logo1.png" alt="Logo" onclick="location.href = 'homepage.html'" height="100" width="100" />


                       <div id="bn">

                <div id="tablepages">
                    <div class="scrollling">       
                            </div>
                </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </center>

            <div id="nb">
                <br />
                <div id="tablepage">
                    <div class="scrolllong">       
                            </div>
                </div>
                    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/profpic.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my php page:**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mobileleavedatabase');
                if(!$link){
                die('Cannot connect to the DB');
                }
$data = array();
$verify_query = "Select user.userID, user.Name, leaveofabsence.LeaveReason, mc.MedicalInstitution, mc.images_path, mc.StartDate, mc.EndDate From mc Inner Join user on user.userID = mc.UserID Inner Join leaveofabsence on leaveofabsence.LeaveID = mc.LeaveID where Status = 'Pending'";
$q = $link->query($verify_query);
while ($row=$q->fetch_assoc()){
 $data[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**and this is my js page :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/MobileHrPHP/administratormc.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (results) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(results);
            $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                $(".scrolllong").append("<div class=" + "listviewborder" + ">" +
                        "<a href=" + "#hide" + field.userID + " class=" + "hide" + " id=" + "hide" + field.userID + ">+</a>" +
                        "<a href=" + "#show" + field.userID + " class=" + "show" + " id=" + "show" + field.userID + ">-</a>" +
                        "<div class=" + "headoflist" + ">" + field.Name + "</div>" +                        
                        "<div class=" + "list" + ">" +
                        "<p>Leave Reason: " + field.LeaveReason + "</p>" +
                        "<p>MC Instituition: " + field.MedicalInstitution + "</p>" +
                        "<p>MC Image: " + field.images_path + "<img id=" + "MCImg" + "alt='Image' title='image'>" + "</p>" +                     
                        "<p>Start Date: " + field.StartDate + "</p>" +
                        "<p>End Date: " + field.EndDate + "</p>" +  
                        "<p>" + "<a onclick = clik("+ field.userID +") "+ "id=" + " accept" +  ">Accept</a>" +
                        "<a href=" + "declinationmc.html?UserID=" + field.userID + "&LeaveID=" + field.LeaveID + ">Decline</a>" +   
                        " </div></div>" 
                        );      
            });


        }
    });
});


function clik(user){
    var userid = user;
    alert(userid);
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "&userid=" + userid,
        url: "http://localhost/MobileHrPHP/acceptationmc.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Your comment was successfully added');
                    location.href = 'administratormc.html';
                },
                error: function(){
//                    console.log(data);
                    alert('There was an error adding your comment' );
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: `<img>` `src` is not set at `<img id=" + "MCImg" + "alt='Image' title='image'>"`

Comment: what do i need to put in src

Comment: `<img src="/path/to/img">`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img